# In Django, how do I re-order items in a ValuesQuerySet object?

Tags: django

I currently have the following `ValuesQuerySet` object after running the following code:

```
sites = Sites.objects.values('name')

# output
[{'name': u'serverfault.com'}, {'name': u'superuser.com'}, {'name': u'stackoverflow.com'}]
```

I want to move `stackoverflow.com` to the beginning of the list, how do I do that?  I can exclude `stackoverflow.com` but I don't believe I can append the new list to it with ValuesQuerySet.  If what I want is not possible, is there a method which can convert a `ValuesQuerySet` into a regular Python list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list(sites)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sites.objects.order_by(
    Case(
        When(name='stackoverflow.com', then=0),
        default=1,
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).values('name')
```